# Compare rows two tables

Tags: sql-server

I want to compare rows value from one table with rows value from another table. Structure of the first table is :

[image: Structure of table]

The other table is more complex than first table and have the same structure but number of rows is million rows, by the way first have 60.000 rows.

I need to compare these two tables by `biling_profiles` so I have an insight into the price but that billing profile turn in the column. It's easily done using the left outer join because approximately 6 or 7 `billing_profiles` . Next thing I need is that if the other table has no value (for example, the first table has row with (destination 201425, cost 2,624) and the other does not , then I have trimmed one character from right to left and then search (destination - 20142). If no again result i repeat again trim from right to left (destination - 2014), when i found same destination then show in table)

So, how to solve that ?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Id
FROM
    table1 A
    INNER JOIN table 2B
        ON A.Id = B.Id AND A.biling_profiles = B.biling_profiles
```

or

```
    select t1.biling_profiles,t2.biling_profiles
    from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2 on
    t1.id= t2.id
    where t1.biling_profiles= @biling_profiles
```

Comment: Ok. thanks these queries is to show the same values from two tables, and i want to show if there is no relationship and then compare and trim.